# Force Babel to transform import into require?

Tags: javascript, babeljs

After I upgrade from Node 12 to Node 14, Babel stopped transforming `import` into `require`. Here's my Babel config:

```
export default {
  presets: [
    ['@babel/preset-env', {
      useBuiltIns: 'usage',
      corejs: '3',
      modules: false,
      targets: {
        node: 12,
      },
    }],
    '@babel/preset-typescript',
  ],
  plugins: [
    '@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import',
    '@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties',
    '@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining',
  ],
  sourceType: 'unambiguous',
  overrides: [
    {
      test: ['./web'],
      presets: [
        ['@babel/preset-env', {
          useBuiltIns: 'usage',
          corejs: '3',
        }],
      ],
      plugins: [
        '@babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx',
        ['module-resolver', {
          root: ['./shared', './web'],
          extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.ts', '.tsx'],
        }],
      ],
      env: {
        production: {
          plugins: ['transform-react-remove-prop-types'],
        },
      },
    },
    {
      test: ['./server'],
      plugins: [
        ['module-resolver', {
          root: ['./shared', './server'],
          extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.ts', '.tsx'],
        }],
      ],
    },
    {
      test: ['./shared'],
      plugins: [
        ['module-resolver', {
          root: ['./shared'],
          extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.ts', '.tsx'],
        }],
      ],
    },
  ],
};
```

How can I get Babel to transform `import`?

Comment: Have you tried `targets: { node: 14 }` ?

Comment: I added `node: 12` because Node 13 added native `import` support. That didn't work btw

Answer (score 0):

You should set `@babel/preset-env`'s `modules` option to `'cjs'` so that it transforms your module to CommonJS (which uses `require`). A value of `false` tells Babel not to perform a module transform.

[Babel's docs](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-preset-env#modules):

> "amd" | "umd" | "systemjs" | "commonjs" | "cjs" | "auto" | false, defaults to "auto".
>
> Enable transformation of ES module syntax to another module type. Note that cjs is just an alias for commonjs.
>
> Setting this to false will preserve ES modules. Use this only if you intend to ship native ES Modules to browsers. If you are using a bundler with Babel, the default modules: "auto" is always preferred.